# jade template engine greeting logged in user

Tags: node.js, pug, express

I'm trying to understand how jade template engine works. I would like to open one of my .jade file from the route in my node.js + express.js server passing some variable (for example if a user logs in, I would like to greet him). I know it's possible because I've been pointed to jade for that, but I can't find a good example on jade's github about that.

Does anyone of you already solved this and can help me? Thanks.

Comment: `p= "hello" + user.name`

Comment: Where is this code going to be put? In my .jade file? Is the .jade file going to read variables from the code calling it? And which code should I call to be able to give jade this possibility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**route:**

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res){
   var usr = new User({username: 'myname'})   
   res.render('login/success', {
     title: 'Welcome',
     user: usr
   });
 });
```

**login/success.jade:**

```
h2 Welcome #{user.username}
```

or any number of other options. see https://github.com/visionmedia/jade for more help with the templating language.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So simple, yet not really documented... I had a look there before a couple of time (especially the example folder) but didn't really managed to get what I was searching for. Thanks again!